# Trying to setup a NextJS website on Heroku with a custom domain from another provider (names.co.uk)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, dns, next.js

I have a website for a client which I am wanting to host on Heroku with a custom domain from https://www.names.co.uk/. https://www.names.co.uk/ has the domain name (example.co.uk) and a GeoTrust QuickSSL Premium Certificate connected to it.

I need the website to work from the following URLS and force HTTPS if someone uses HTTP:

```
http://www.example.co.uk
https://www.example.co.uk
http://example.co.uk
https://example.co.uk
```

I understand that names.co.uk does not support using CNAMES (which Heroku provides) on the root domain (example.co.uk) but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong to prevent it from working.

I am unsure what domain names I need to add in Heroku each of them and whether I need to use the SSL certificate offered by Heroku. I also am unsure as to what I need to provide in names.co.uk in terms of A-NAMES, CNAMES and Web Forwards.

It would be much appreciated if anyone has any advice on how I can configure this properly, if it is even possible to get all these URLS to work with Heroku and Namesco.

Apologies if I haven't explained anything clearly, I'm relatively new to DNS and deployment and cannot seem to solve the issue by following Heroku's or Namesco's documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Heroku's SSL certificate would make the process easier, so unless you have a reason to use Namecheap's SSL certificate, I recommend going with Heroku.
The Heroku certificate is automatically applied and Heroku automatically forces HTTPS.

It's recommended to use either `example.com` or `www.example.com`. Assuming you want to use the `www` subdomain this is how to proceed:

Redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com` by following Namecheap's documentation on [how to create a URL redirect](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/2237/how-to-redirect-a-url-for-a-domain).

Then follow the Heroku documentation to [add your custom domain to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains):

- `heroku domains:add www.example.com`
- Then update your DNS settings. By default your DNS provider is Namecheap. See Namecheap documentation on [how to create a CNAME record](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9646/2237/how-to-create-a-cname-record-for-your-domain). Namecheap recommends against setting up a CNAME record for a bare domain, so if you want to use `example.com` as your preferred domain this step would be slightly different.

And that's it!

Keep in mind that the website will still be available on your Heroku domain: `example.herokuapp.com`. You may also want to redirect this to your preferred domain.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just wanted to clarify that it was Names.co.uk I am using not Namecheap. In names.co.uk it does not allow me to use CNAMES on the route domain and instead only. I have added the www.example.com domain into my heroku app and added the CNAME provided into namescheaps DNS settings under the www subdomain. However the certificate on Heroku seems to fail.

Comment: Sorry, got confused between names / namecheap. Can you confirm you have a paid Heroku plan? How do you see that the Heroku certificate isn't working? On a paid plan, in the settings tabs, under SSL Certificates, there should be "Your certificate is automatically managed." and a green tick. Is that not the case?

Comment: No problem, easy mistake! Yes I can confirm I am using Heroku's Hobby plan. I did have the certificates working at some point but now it keeps failing since I was messing with moving the app to Vercel instead. I have added the www domain into heroku, which then displays DNS verified before showing red text saying failed, where the green tick normally appears.

Comment: This link shows the statuses I am talking about - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#view-your-certificate-status. When I tried using Vercel instead of Heroku I noticed it kept spamming trying to get an SSL certificate so I have an inkling that I could be blacklisted by Let's Encrypt or something like that.

Comment: It looks like Heroku could be hitting Let's Encrypt rate limit. Does `heroku certs:auto` give more information? If that's the case you could wait for a few days and start again. Until then, or as an alternative, you could upload your Names.co.uk certificate to Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#manually-uploading-certificates-and-intermediaries

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I got in touch with Heroku through their support and they made me aware they I had made too many requests to Let’s Encrypt in a short space of time so they have stopped me from trying to get another one until a week after my first request (3 days). They also let me know that if I wanted to get the website to work on the root domain with HTTPS I would have to transfer my domain to another DNS provider. I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: You're welcome! All the best with these next steps!